# Unable to convert string to Json string?

Tags: java

I have collected data from some third party. From their i am getting string look like json string

```
'[{LastName=jkl, FirstName=ghi, EmailAddress=ghi@jkl.com, IncludeInEmails=true}]'
```

but doesn't have double quotes around key and value.

one solution is.
I can read string and put it into map and convert map into json string.

is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You probably want your 3rd party vendor to fix their service instead of fixing this yourself.

Comment: so my first solution i.e using map is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to remove all the `[{` characters, split the string by the `,` and then the split the resulting list of strings by `=` to get a list of key value pairs.